# Only reading serial data once

Tags: arduino

I have the following code but can only transmit `m1 on`  one time at power on. After that my arduino ignores serial data I send to it.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(1, 3, 2);

char inData[20]; // Allocate some space for the string
char inChar=-1; // Where to store the character read
byte index = 0; // Index into array; where to store the character

void setup()
{
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000.0);
  stepper.setAcceleration(1000);
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Begin serial communiation at 9600.
  Serial.write("Power On");
}
char Comp(char* This) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
                                   // there you know there is data
    {
        if(index < 19) // One less than the size of the array
        {
            inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
            inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
            index++; // Increment where to write next
            inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(inData,This)  == 0) {
        for (int i=0;i<19;i++) {
            inData[i]=0;
        }
        index=0;
        return(0);
    }
    else {
        return(1);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    if (Comp("m1 on")==0) {
        Serial.write("Motor 1 -> Online\n");
    }
    if (Comp("m1 off")==0) {
        Serial.write("Motor 1 -> Offline\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your serial output?

Comment: inputting `m1 on` or `m1 off` will yield the appropriate `Motor 1 -> Online\n` or `Motor 1 -> Offline\n` response, but this can only be performed one time.

Comment: Then you are getting stuck in an infinite loop. Force your while loop to break after a couple iterations to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to rest on the (wrong) assumption that the send string will be completely available as soon as the first character is read. So maybe you received "m1" but not yet " on" when you start parsing. This in turn ensures that you string compare will always fail and your code seems to be stuck.

I suggest you add Serial.print statements in suitable places to see what your code actually received and how it handled it. Once you have enough prints in place you will better understand what is going on and be able to fix this on your own.

BTW: the easiest fix is to not use strings for simple commands but characters instead. Another simple fix is to [give the parsing work to a suitable library.](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/messenger) There are other similar libraries out there as well.

Another solution is to parse the serial interface with a finite state machine like I implemented it for [this experiment.](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/measurements/flexible-sweep/) This is most probably the best solution for keeping ram / resource consumption low but expensive in terms of development time.